# Change URL of browsable API of django rest framework from 127.0.0.1:8000 to 127.0.0.1:8000/api

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I followed the simple quickstart tutorial in the official documentation of django rest framework.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/

The tutorial works fine. The URL of the browsable API is at `127.0.0.1:8000`. How do I change it to `127.0.0.1:8000/api`?

The code for `urls.py`;

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from tutorial.quickstart import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', views.GroupViewSet)

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

I am using django v4, python v3.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the prefix via `path()`, like you've done for `api-auth/`.

(This is not DRF-specific; it's just the [regular `path()` function you use to mount views onto URLs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urls/#path))

```
path('', include(router.urls)),
```

->

```
path('api/', include(router.urls)),
```

Comment: Thanks. That was fast. Tested that your answer works. 
I'm newbie to django. Would you happen to know purpose of `path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))`? I browsed to http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-auth but received 404 error.

Comment: There's nothing directly under `/api-auth/`, but you can see for yourself by [opening up the `rest_framework/urls.py` module you've included](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/urls.py)...